# Python Selenium 'WebDriver' object has no attribute firefox error

Tags: python, web, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape some content from web using selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
```

And I get the following error, Thanks in advance.

```
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Firefox'
```

Comment: check whether selenium is properly installed. use `pip install -U selenium`  for the latest version if you want. uninstall and install the `selenium` module again. what is the current selenium version?

Comment: What is the name of your python file ?

Comment: Don't name your python file as `selenium.py`. rename it. because python considers the python file/script as `selenium` module, which is not.

Comment: Do you have Firefox installed?

Comment: I didn't name it selenium, just normal file name. The version of selenium is 3.0.2 , I have reinstalled it, but it still display same error msg

Comment: Yes, I have my Firefox installed

Comment: Are you sure that the path to your firefox driver is correct?

Comment: try `print(webdriver.__file__)`. What is the path you got in output? Does it really equals to  `...\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\__init__.py`?

Comment: I have faced this issue once when i had both python 2.7 and python 3.5 were installed in my computer.
First I installed `pip` for python3
`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`
then I installed selenium for python3
`python3 -m pip insall selenium`